# Amazon SNS, how to find the source of an event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

So I'm trying to find the source of a strange bug which causes unusual invocation spikes for a particular lambda function. So far, I've added logging functionality to the lambdas and redeployed to glean more info about the context and event objects that trigger the lambda.

So I want to know where these events are originating, and from those aforementioned logged event objects I've found the TopicArn that is the culprit, but how do I go about finding the guilty publisher in this relationship? Any ideas or something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) enabled? You should be able to use CloudTrail to [log all the calls to your SNS topics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html).

Comment: What if the entity that's doing these cyclical invocation spikes are "AssumedRole" types? I already have CloudTrail enabled.

Comment: The `AssumeRole` event is also logged in CloudTrail.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help Mark

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you logged you might want to attach an SQS queue to the topic too.  This would give you the full packet.  I can see in one of mine that there is something like:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "7f47b81a-10cc-4b28-be35-123456789",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789",
  "time": "2017-02-03T18:28:52Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789:rule\/5_min_scheduler"
  ],
  "detail": {

  }
}
```

This is, obviously, from a cloudwatch scheduled event but it does have a source.  I don't know for sure that yours will but it's easy to have a topic push to a queue in addition to the Lambda to assist in debugging.